# Spring-security <intercept-url requires-channel="https"/>

Tags: https, spring-security

Hi. In Spring-Security after login success, to redirect the `intercept-url`
as `https` I am  using the attribute `required-channel="https"`. It is working fine, 
but after that every url is continuing with https. But I want only intercept-url to 
redirected with https.

```
<security:http  auto-config='true'>

    <security:intercept-url  pattern="/member/**"  access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>

    <security:access-denied-handler ref="accessDeninedHandler"/>

    <security:form-login login-page="/login.htm?form" 
         authentication-success-handler-ref="/"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?form" /> 

    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout.htm" logout-success-url="/"/>

    <security:remember-me key="remembermekey" services-ref="rememberMeServices" />

</security:http>
```

Answer (score 0):

*First*: Your pattern might contain many URLs. You should check if your URLs do not start with `/member/...`

*Second*: If that's checked and it's not the problem, simply introduce new `intercept-url` and use `requires-channel="http"` for them.

**OR** use `< security:http pattern="Other Patterns" security="none" />` for the rest of URLs.